# How to politely say I worked at the same company for 4 years in a specific period?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

I worked at the same company for 4 years as a summer job between November and January on every year. I am graduating and I would like to write it into my CV/Resume because I don't really have a rich work experience in other area and the skills that I learnt from there are particular useful and relevant to the career that I want to get in.

Would it be inappropriate to just put *2013-2017* in my work experience ?

What is the most suitable way to express this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing just 2013–2017 implies at least three complete years, so that's not the thing to put down.

Even "2013–2017 (Nov–Jan)" as has been [suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/371451/18696) is not entirely clear. Does it mean November 2013 to January 2017? If it requires thought to tease out, it's not going to help on a CV.

I'd suggest being explicit, using the phrase *seasonal work* or *summer work*:

> 2013–2017 Hop-picking with Grobeer Pty (Seasonal work November to January)

Comment: And sorry for not voting up your answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

I would just say

> 2013-2017 (Nov-Jan)

If you write

> 2013-2017

that could be seen as misleading

Comment: Thank you, I am also considering to add a extra sentence about this